# How do I get my EE dynamic fields to display content in my Angular tab component?

Tags: angular, angular-components, expressionengine

I created a vertical tab bar component, it works perfectly on my local, when I add my component to my Expression Engine template, in the inspector, it shows that my component is there, but all the fields are empty. So its not displaying my EE fields content within the component. Breaking my head trying to figure out why.

My component consists of a main folder for the dynamic tab bar, then 3 other folders with seperate parts namely, the dynamic-tab-selector, dynamic-tab-section & the dynamic-tab-item which binds the selector and section together. Source/example I used https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/create-a-fully-dynamic-tab-component-in-angular-9f5187ab35dc

I previously got **ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked**. I've searched high and low for a solution. Coming this fix.

***constructor(private changeRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
ngAfterViewChecked(): void { this.changeRef.detectChanges(); }***

Which solved the error on my local, but now my component isnt displaying the data fields EE.

Has it got something to do with that fix??

dynamic-tab.component.ts

```
import {
Component,
OnInit,
ContentChildren,
QueryList,
AfterContentInit,
Input,
AfterContentChecked,
} from "@angular/core";
import { BoltDynamicTabItemComponent } from "../bolt-dynamic-tab/bolt-dynamic-tab-item/bolt-dynamic-tab-item.component";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { startWith, map, delay } from "rxjs/operators";
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
 selector: 'bolt-dynamic-tab',
 templateUrl: 'bolt-dynamic-tab.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['bolt-dynamic-tab.component.scss']
 })

 export class BoltDynamicTabComponent implements AfterContentInit, AfterContentChecked {

  @ContentChildren(BoltDynamicTabItemComponent)
  tabs: QueryList<BoltDynamicTabItemComponent>;

  tabItems$: Observable<BoltDynamicTabItemComponent[]>;

  activeTab: BoltDynamicTabItemComponent;


  constructor(private changeRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void { this.changeRef.detectChanges(); }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
  this.tabItems$ = this.tabs.changes
  .pipe(startWith(""))
  .pipe(delay(0))
  .pipe(map(() => this.tabs.toArray()));
  }

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
   //choose the default tab
   // we need to wait for a next VM turn,
   // because Tab item content, will not be initialized yet
   if (!this.activeTab) {
    this.activeTab = this.tabs.first;
   }
 }

 selectTab(tabItem: BoltDynamicTabItemComponent) {
   if (this.activeTab === tabItem) {
     return;
  }

  if (this.activeTab) {
    this.activeTab.isActive = false;
  
   }

   this.activeTab = tabItem;

   tabItem.isActive = true;
 }
}
```

dynamic-tab.component.html

```
 <div class="bolt-flex bolt-flex-between bolt-flex-wrap bolt-width-1-1">
    <div class="bolt-width-1-3@m heading">
       <div class="tabs-header">
         <div
          class="tab-label"
          (click)="selectTab(item)"
          [class.active]="activeTab === item"
          *ngFor="let item of tabItems$ | async"
          >
          <ng-container *ngIf="item.labelComponent">
            <ng-content *ngTemplateOutlet="item.labelComponent.labelContent">
            </ng-content>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container *ngIf="!item.labelComponent">
            {{ item.label }}
          </ng-container>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div> 
     <div class="bolt-width-2-3@m">
       <div class="tabs-body">
         <ng-container *ngIf="activeTab && activeTab.bodyComponent">
           <ng-content *ngTemplateOutlet="activeTab.bodyComponent.bodyContent">
           </ng-content>
         </ng-container>
      </div>
   </div> 
  </div>
```

dynamic-tab.component.scss

```
@use 'projects/bolt-red/src/theme/config' as config;


:host{
font-family: config.$bolt-base-font;
display: flex;
align-items: flex-start;
padding: 0 40px;

:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }

.tabs-header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.tab-label {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(242, 242, 242);
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #999;
  cursor: pointer;

  h4 {
      font-size: 20px;
      line-height:30px;
  }
}
.tabs-body {
    ::ng-deep ul {
      margin: 20px;
      z-index: 1;
      list-style: none;
      line-height: inherit;
      padding:0;
    }

    ::ng-deep ul li {
      position: relative;
      border-left: 1px solid hsla(0,0%,80%,.6);
      margin: 4px 4px 16px;
      padding-left: 20px;
      font-weight: 300;
    }
}

.active {
  color: #3a3a3a;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #b83426;
}
```

}

Comment: Put the project on github I'll take a look.

Comment: Hi John, my code wasn't the problem. Certain features I used is not part of the project feature set that I'm doing. Thanx for the willingness to help